# Улучшение страницы справки «Что должно содержать краткое описание метки?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Ссылка на текущую версию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts
Заголовок: What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?

---

Tags are the de-facto map of allowed (and implicitly disallowed by omission) topics on your site. That’s why the first two pages of tags should have excellent tag wiki excerpts at a minimum. If they have great, complete [tag wikis](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/), that’s even better, but you have to crawl before you can walk. Focusing on the ~500 character excerpt is a simple way to get started — and that text is surfaced in a bunch of places on the site, including tag mouseovers.

### Guidelines for writing useful tag excerpts

1. **The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.** You only have ~500 plain text characters for the excerpt, so don’t feel obligated to cover everything in it! Save that for the 30,000+ character Markdown tag wiki. The excerpt should define the shared quality of questions containing this tag — boiled down to a few short sentences.
2. **Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag**, unless it is highly specialized. The “email” tag, for example, does *not* need to explain what email is. I think we can safely assume most internet users know what email is; there’s no value in a boilerplate explanation of email to anyone.
3. **Concentrate on what a tag means to *your* community.** For “email” on Server Fault, mention the server aspects of email including POP3, SMTP, IMAP, and server software. For “email” on Super User, mention desktop email clients and explicitly exclude webmail, as that would be more appropriate for http://webapps.stackexchange.com.
4. **Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.** In other words, *what kinds of questions should have this tag?* Tags only exist as ways of organizing questions, so if we don’t provide proper guidance on which questions *need* this tag, they won’t get tagged at all, rendering the tag excerpt moot. Think of it as a sales pitch: in a room full of tags screaming “pick me!”, what would convince a question asker to select your tag?
5. **Some tags are common knowledge.** Most tags require a bit of explanation in the excerpt, even if it’s only 3 or 4 words. But if the tag is common knowledge — that is, if you *walked up to any random person on the street and said the tag word to them*, and they would know what you were talking about — then don’t bother explaining the tag at all. Stick to usage of the tag within your community in the excerpt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заголовок: Что должно содержать краткое описание метки?

---

Метки – это фактически карта допустимых (и, соответственно, недопустимых) тем на вашем сайте. Поэтому как минимум первые две страницы меток должны сопровождаться отличным [кратким описанием меток](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/). Если это будут хорошие, полные описания меток, это будет ещё лучше, но, чтобы ходить, сначала нужно научиться ползать. Лучше всего начать с написания краткого описания из ~500 символов — этот текст выводится в разных элементах сайта, включая всплывающие окна меток.

Руководство по написанию полезных кратких описаний меток

1. **Краткое описание – это сжатая презентация метки.** Краткое описание ограничено ~500 символами неформатированного текста, поэтому необязательно упоминать в нём всё, что связано с меткой! Приберегите подробности для описания метки в системе Markdown, состоящего из 30 000+ символов. Краткое описание должно определять качество вопросов с этой меткой — сжатое до нескольких коротких фраз.
2. **Избегайте общего описания концепции, лежащей в основе метки**, за исключением случаев, когда она слишком узкоспециальная. Метка [электронная почта], например, не должна объяснять, что такое электронная почта. Скорее всего большинство пользователей Интернета знают, что это такое; подробное описание электронной почты никому не интересно.
3. **Сконцентрируйтесь на том, что метка означает для вашего сообщества.** Метка [электронная почта] для темы «Ошибка сервера» должна содержать серверные аспекты электронной почты, включая POP3, SMTP, IMAP, и серверное ПО. Метка [электронная почта] для темы «Привилегированный пользователь», должна описывать почтовые клиенты для ПК и не содержать конкретные веб-службы электронной почты, так как они скорее относятся к [http://webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).
4. **Напишите общее правило использования этой метки.** Другими словами, какие вопросы должны сопровождаться этой меткой? Метки предназначены только для организации вопросов, поэтому без правил использования метки в определённых вопросах, эти вопросы совсем не будут сопровождаться метками, что делает описание метки чисто теоретическим. Думайте об этом, как о рекламе: в комнате, полной меток, которые кричат «выбери меня!», что сможет убедить задающего вопрос выбрать именно вашу метку?
5. **Часть меток являются общим знанием.** Большинству меток требуется краткое обозначение, даже если это всего 3-4 слова. Но если метка является общим знанием — то есть, *если вы подойдете к случайному прохожему на улице и скажете ему имя метки*, он будет знать о чём идет речь, и о чём вы говорите — в этом случае можно обойтись совсем без обозначения. В кратком описании метки укажите только то, чем является метка для сообщества.