# Актуализация страниц справки силами сообщества

Tags: предложение, локализация, справка

Статьи справки, ссылки на которые можно видеть на [основной странице справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) не доступны для редактирования через систему перевода transifex. Свободно редактировать их могут только сотрудники Stack Overflow. Менеджер сообщества также [может](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4915/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0#comment17937_4915) отметить статью как разрешённую для редактирования модераторами.

Многие страницы справки содержат опечатки, неточности перевода или скриншоты из уже не актуальной или даже вовсе английской версии сайта. Просить менеджера сообщества вносить самостоятельно правки в такие документы не считаю правильным, у него есть дела поважнее.

Поэтому хочу высказать предложение о необходимости выложить в общий доступ здесь на Мете в виде вопрос/ответ тексты этих страниц, чтобы все участники сообщества могли предлагать (или вносить самостоятельно) свои правки в страницы справочных документов для их актуализации. Для каталогизации этих страниц разумно завести отдельный вопрос, который будет отправной точкой, т.е. по сути содержанием (редактируемым аналогом) основной страницы справки.

В качестве вопроса по каждому тексту справки предлагаю разместить английский (исходный) вариант текста. А в качестве ответа — имеющийся на текущий момент вариант русского перевода. При такой организации можно будет ловить ещё и ошибки/неточности перевода.

С некоторой периодичностью (или по необходимости) с учётом наличия изменений модератор или менеджер сообщества может обновлять текст справки сайта из соответствующего ответа.

Некоторые отдельные страницы уже добавлены на Мету:

- [Улучшение страницы справки «Что должно содержать краткое описание метки?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4914/176217)
- [Редактирование страницы справки «How to Ask Questions in Private Beta»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4879/176217)

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6+%5B%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%5D+is%3Aq

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/981/181472

Comment: `избранный модератор не обладает правами для доступа к этим текстам для редактирования` – обладает, но одновременно для правки могут быть открыты только несколько статей. Открывает их CM.

Comment: @NickVolynkin об этом где-то есть инфа в открытом доступе?

Comment: Не помню. Можно явно описать API ПубликаторСправки и сказать, что мы четверо его реализуем. )