# Заменить ссылку на странице "Голосовать против"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

На странице ["Голосовать против"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) заменить ссылку внизу, вместо ссылки на [«vote up»](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) en меты указать ссылку на [«Голосовать за»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Картинки знаков на русском для замены на странице заодно (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

[image: Спортивное поведение]

[image: Сторонник]

[image: Электорат]

[image: Глас народа]

[image: Голос народ]

[image: Гражданский долг]

Comment: и *[знаки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn3ch.png)* на странице *[голосовать за](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)* нужно заменить на русские.

Comment: @Alex кстати да. Добавил картинки в вопрос сразу.

Comment: А зачем по каждой ссылке отдельную тему? Например, текущая обсуждаемая ссылка уже [упомянута в списке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4178/176217).

Comment: @alexolut видел эту тему. Но что-то никто не чешется заменить ссылку в справке =/

Comment: @Suvitruf самый простой способ на текущий момент — попросить Николаса расшарить страницу на Мете для дальнейшего редактирования. Если же текущие ссылки ведут на страницы, для которых еще нет перевода, то сначала имеет смысл сделать такой перевод.

Comment: @alexolut было б прикольно, если б на странице самой справки была б кнопка с предложением правки, как для меток )=

Comment: @Suvitruf да, я как-то даже озвучивал подобную идею (или хотел озвучить) ;)

Comment: @alexolut на мета мете никто такой вопрос не поднимал?

Comment: @Suvitruf например, [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279879/339911) для модераторов предложение.

Comment: А вот [моё предложение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4915/176217) с учетом текущих реалий.